# Laravel, Trying to get property of non-object in a blade view

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

EDITED: In a blade, with some data loaded (`$carga` is a collection)

`$carga` is defined as:

```
$carga = UploadsPois::where([
    ['estado_carga', Util::UPLOAD_POIS_CARGA_INGRESADA],
    ['schema_country', $schema_country]
])
    ->with([
        'UserResponsable',
        'Pois' => function ($pois) {
            $pois->where('pois_validate', Util::POIS_INGRESADO);
        },
        'Log' => function ($log) use ($schema_country) {
            $log->where('schema_country', $schema_country)
                ->whereNull('address_id')
                ->orderBy('id', 'desc');
                //->first();
        }
    ])
    ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
    ->get();
```

if I put on a blade:

```
{{$carga->Log()->first()}}
{{ $carga->Log()->first() }}
```

[image]

I get in the screen:

```
{"id":21885,"user_id":380,"accion":"Direcci\u00f3n aprobada","fecha":"2018-03-19 18:47:49","upload_pois_id":617,"address_id":142154,"comentario":"","pois_id":null,"schema_country":"country_cl"} 
{"id":21885,"user_id":380,"accion":"Direcci\u00f3n aprobada","fecha":"2018-03-19 18:47:49","upload_pois_id":617,"address_id":142154,"comentario":"","pois_id":null,"schema_country":"country_cl"}
```

[image]

But if I try to print just "comentario" from that object with:

```
{{ $carga->Log()->first()->comentario }}
```

[image]

I get this error: `Trying to get property of non-object`

[image]

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I said this on your other question, but if `$carga->log->first()` is `null`, you can't call `comentario` on it (as `null->comentario` doesn't work).

Also, **don't use `()` on `log`**; you're using `with()`, so `$carga->log` is available as a property. If you use `()`, you're basically throwing out the entire filter you're applying to `log` in your controller by making a new call to the query builder. **Don't do that** (Have to stress this, as all other answers are suggesting to use `$carga->log()->first()`, but that's just objectively incorrect in this case).

The correct syntax would be:

```
{{ $carga->log->first() ? $carga->log->first()->comentario : 'No comentario...' }}
```

This uses a simply ternary operator to first check if `$carga->log->first()` is not `null`, and prints either the `comentario`, or a simple string `No comentario...`

-- Edit --

I should add that you can (or at least should be able to) use `->first()` in the function, and simply omit `->first()` in the call (saw your other other question, something odd happening there):

```
...
->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();

{{ $carga->log ? $carga->log->comentario : 'No comentario...' }}
```

Either one of these will handle the `null` case that's the root cause of your issue here.

Comment: Yes, I don't know why is happening that with `first()`. Man, I must send you a present for christmass.

Comment: Yeah, doesn't really make sense that the `first()` wouldn't work there, but if it works outside the function, just go with that. And again, thanks for the thought, but don't worry about it :P

Comment: In `UploadsPois` model the Log relation is `return $this->hasMany` maybe is a problem with hasMany and first? and `LogPois`model has `return $this->belongsTo('App\UploadsPois', 'upload_pois_id');` for public function UploadPois()

Comment: You *could* edit the relation to a `hasOne()`, but I'm not sure if your database design would support that. Again, `first()` should work in both spots, as the `first()` method exists on both the query builder and `Collection` classes, but I'm not sure why it doesn't in your case.

Answer (score 0):

this usage means "`Log()`" is a method:

```
{{$carga->Log()->first()}}
```

It should be accessed as a property:

```
{{ $carga->Log->first()->comentario }}->
```